# Script works as WSH, but in a HTA Sub it goes berzerker

Tags: hta

I'm trying to build some Subs inside an HTA that run the following code.  The script works fine as standalone WSH script, but when I put the code in a sub in my HTA it goes BERZERK.  My command window appears a bunch of times, I think it is launching a new process for each WshShell.Sendkeys.  I have tried numerous things, but am obviously missing something.  Even when I have the HTA call the script externally I get the same wacky behavior, but I can run this in a wsh script and it works fine...

Please help!!

```
set WshShell=CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.run "cmd.exe"
WScript.Sleep 500


WshShell.SendKeys "telnet 130.160.176.219 4998"

WshShell.SendKeys ("{Enter}")
WScript.Sleep 5000


WshShell.SendKeys "sendir,1:1,1,37764,1,1,340,168,21,22,21,22,21,22,21,22,21,22,21,22,21,22,21,22,21,64,21,64,21,64,21,64,21,64,21,64,21,64,21,64,21,22,21,64,21,22,21,64,21,22,21,22,21,22,21,22,21,64,21,22,21,64,21,22,21,64,21,64,21,64,21,64,21,4833"
WshShell.SendKeys ("{Enter}")
WScript.Sleep 500
WshShell.SendKeys "sendir,1:1,10,37764,1,1,340,168,21,22,21,22,21,22,21,22,21,22,21,22,21,22,21,22,21,64,21,64,21,64,21,64,21,64,21,64,21,64,21,64,21,64,21,64,21,22,21,22,21,22,21,22,21,64,21,22,21,22,21,22,21,64,21,64,21,64,21,64,21,22,21,64,21,4833"
WshShell.SendKeys ("{Enter}")
WScript.Sleep 500
WshShell.SendKeys "sendir,1:1,5,37764,1,1,340,168,21,22,21,22,21,22,21,22,21,22,21,22,21,22,21,22,21,64,21,64,21,64,21,64,21,64,21,64,21,64,21,64,21,64,21,22,21,64,21,22,21,22,21,22,21,22,21,22,21,22,21,64,21,22,21,64,21,64,21,64,21,64,21,64,21,4833"
WshShell.SendKeys ("{Enter}")
WScript.Sleep 500
WshShell.SendKeys "sendir,1:1,11,37764,1,1,340,168,21,22,21,22,21,22,21,22,21,22,21,22,21,22,21,22,21,64,21,64,21,64,21,64,21,64,21,64,21,64,21,64,21,22,21,64,21,64,21,64,21,64,21,22,21,64,21,22,21,64,21,22,21,22,21,22,21,22,21,64,21,22,21,64,21,4833"
WshShell.SendKeys ("{Enter}")
WScript.Sleep 500
WshShell.SendKeys "sendir,1:1,1,37764,1,1,340,168,21,22,21,22,21,22,21,22,21,22,21,22,21,22,21,22,21,64,21,64,21,64,21,64,21,64,21,64,21,64,21,64,21,22,21,64,21,22,21,64,21,22,21,22,21,22,21,22,21,64,21,22,21,64,21,22,21,64,21,64,21,64,21,64,21,4833"
WshShell.SendKeys ("{Enter}")
WScript.Sleep 1000
WshShell.SendKeys ("^{]}q{Enter}exit{Enter}")
//WScript.Quit
```

Comment: `WScript` is not present in HTA.

Comment: Well.  I got it working.  Except for one bit:  Telnet doesn't receive my escape key.  If I can figure that part out, I am good to go.  I tried using an alternate character (telnet -e z) but when I send "z" i see it echo on the terminal and telnet still doesn't receive escape.  :-?